# Android custom fonts, where to put font file

Tags: android

I have been searching for a way to add custom fonts to an Adroid app in Android studio.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_activty);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/desyrel");
        textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    }
```

My question is, where to put the font file..I have searched quite a bit, and most sources indicate I put it in an assets folder..the only assets folder I can find is an "intermediaries" folder...which does not seem right (I tried it, font did not change).

I was clued in on this:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1019

The code there matches what I have somewhat...

I think if I can just find where to put the file, this will work.

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: What's wrong with the `assets` folder?

Comment: create a folder named "assets" under your "main" directory and put your custom fonts there

Answer (score 0):

you can put your font file in assets folder.In assets folder make folder fonts and just put your font in this folder